# How can I count and display only the words that are repeated more than once using unix commands?

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I am trying to count and display only the words that are repeated more than once in a file. The basic idea is:

- You are given a file with names and characters like commas, colons, slashes, etc..
- Use the `cut` command to display only the first names in the file (other commands are also allowed).
- Count and then display only the names repeated more than once.

I got to the point of counting and displaying all the names. However, I haven't found a way to display and to count only those names repeated more than once.

Here is a section of the file:

```
user1:x:80:200:Mia,Spurs:/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:80:200:Martha,Dalton:/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:80:200:Lucy,Carlson:/home/user3:/bin/bash
user4:x:80:200:Carl,Bingo:/home/user4:/bin/bash
```

Here is what I have been able to do:

```
Daniel@Daniel-MacBook-Pro Files % cut -d ":" -f 5-5 file1 | cut -d "," -f 1-1 | sort -n | uniq -c
   1 Mia
   3 Martha
   1 Lucy
   1 Carl
   1 Jessi
   1 Joke
   1 Jim
   2 Race
   1 Sem
   1 Shirly
   1 Susan
   1 Tim
```

Comment: Use `uniq -d` to print only the duplicates.

Comment: How can I keep the count while displaying the repeated names?

Comment: Use `uniq -d -c`

Comment: I tried it but it throws me a usage message "usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]]"

Comment: Why are you using the `-n` option to `sort`? They're not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the rows with count `1` with `grep`.

```
cut -d ":" -f 5 file1 | cut -d "," -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 '
```

Comment: Thank you so much, grep -v '^ *1' worked perfectly!